# change background color of each string after a foreach loop

Tags: php, css

Rather a simple question, but I can get a grasp it. so i have this code.

```
<?php
$names = array('ronny','antony');

foreach($names as $name){

echo '<div style="background: green;" class="name">'.$name.'</div><br>';

}
```

How can I change the background of each name? Like ronny's background to be green and antony's to be orange?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<?php
$names = array('ronny' => '#00ff00','antony' =>'#ff0000');

foreach($names as $name => $color){
    echo '<div style="background: ' . $color . ';" class="name">'.$name.'</div><br>';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use CSS since you can put the name as a class

Add this to your CSS file

```
.ronny  {background-color: green}
.antony {background-color: orange}
```

Edit:

add the name to your class

```
echo '<div class="name '.$name.'">'.$name.'</div><br>';
```

Edit 2:

mathielo makes a good point that this would only work if $name is one word.

However, you can use other class names to describe the people (employee, boss, etc.) depending on your scenario.

Comment: what the heck does `class"name $name"` do? Don't you want `echo '<div style="background: green;" class="name '.$name.'">'.$name.'</div><br>';`

Comment: Sorry. I fixed the quotes. Should output class="name ronny"

Comment: This is not a very good solution as the name could be "John Smith". This would be a problem for a CSS class name.

Comment: Well OP didn't say that. I still think it would be better to use class names instead of inline styles.

Comment: I agree with Vlad, I think this is a better solution, that said, you should probably put something in your post mentioning @mathielo's point, you would earn a +1 from me for doing so :P

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I expressed myself poorly. I do think using class is better, but I wanted to point out that it is risky to use a person's name for a CSS class. It would be safer to rely on something like person ID, such as `.person1` and `.person2` - but that depends on what other information you have about whoever is on the list :)

Comment: We're all in agreement! There just wasn't much info available so I went with what I had.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something more dynamic (usually used by larger lists), like switching background color for odd/even rows, you could use something like this:

```
<?php
$names = array('ronny','antony');

foreach($names as $key => $name){

$color = ($key % 2 === 0) ? 'green' : 'orange';

echo '<div style="background: '.$color.';" class="name">'.$name.'</div><br />';

}
?>
```